# Get part of the response body using python

Tags: python, string, request, byte, response

I'm getting a response from a server:

```
B�
QeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.Mzc1Mjk4MjUzNjA1.PFblnWR46sByMIZX2fmot9SB8CNYDwHyDOduIf29Gn8$04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c"5ecf7534b4ccd20100d29378*�所
```

After I use encoding on the response:

```
response = r.text.encode('utf8')
```

I have this in my response variable:

```
b'B\xe2\x80\xba\x01\nQeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.Mzc1Mjk4MjUzNjA1.GKjZw55OvoNpH4vOw0jMSQoCYQ3mIn4b0Hq7Ye5S3wA\x12$04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c"\x185ecf7534b4ccd20100d29378*\x06\x08\xc3\x80\xc2\xa4\xc3\x93\xe2\x82\xac\x01'
```

I'm struggling with getting this part **04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c** using different ways like

```
result = re.search('\x12$(.*)\x18', response)
print(result)
```

result = None.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get **04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c** as a text.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Edit: I've removed "**" characters from the response as it was an attempt to make necessary part bold.

Comment: maybe you get result compressed with `gzip` or `br`  and you should use hearder to inform server that you want normal content (`'deflat'`)

Comment: if you need text between `**` then `text.split('**')` or `bytes.split( b'**' )`

Comment: if have data in bytes then use also bytes in searching.

Comment: The search pattern itself is not working because `$` is a special symbol - it must be escaped in order to be matched: `'\x12\$(.*)\x18'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `$` character and group the characters to avoid calling `split`:

```py
re.search('(\x12\$)(.*)(\x18)', response.decode('utf-8'))[2]
Out[38]: '04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c"'
```

Comment: I grouped characters and also removed encoding on a response so I don't need to decode it again and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in bytes then you should use search bytes

But main problem is that `$` has special meaning in regex - end of line -  and you have to use `\$`

```
import re

data = b'B\xe2\x80\xba\x01\nQeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.Mzc1Mjk4MjUzNjA1.GKjZw55OvoNpH4vOw0jMSQoCYQ3mIn4b0Hq7Ye5S3wA\x12$04059f6f-sdfs-2df2-lj2k-ce310d7e3e8c"\x185ecf7534b4ccd20100d29378*\x06\x08\xc3\x80\xc2\xa4\xc3\x93\xe2\x82\xac\x01'

result = re.search(b'\$(.*)"', data)
print(result[1].decode())
```

Comment: I've eddited the code. There should not be any "**"chars in the data.

Comment: I changed answer. You have to use `\$`